# nox keep spawning nox_adb

Tags: android-emulator, firewall

I use Nox as Android emulator. It worked fine. But the other day I did a little cleanup on my machine, installing CCleaner, MalwareBytes and Comodo firewall.

I tend to do pretty restrictive stuff, but even if they are all turned out Nox has an issue now.

It looks like it's working fine, but in Process Explorer I see that Nox.exe keeps spawning nox_adb process (connect to 127.0.0.1) that spawns a conhost.exe. They immediately die. And it spawns new ones. Like every two seconds.

Any idea what could cause that ? How to investigate why they are dying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would still like to know why and/or how to stop it but I got a workaround:

1. Launch Nox. => Issue always happen
2. Launch the multiplayer
3. Kill Nox.exe instance from Process explorer
4. Relaunch it from the multiplayer => Issue may happen but not always
5. Repeat 3-4 until it does not happen.

Works with several instances